# post value in perl cgi and HTML not inserting properly

Tags: html, perl, cgi

i am new to Perl and using Perl in my back end script and HTML in front end and CGI framework . Initially i am reading some details from flat file and displaying them . I am then trying to print the details in the form of checkboxes. i am using use Data::Dumper; module to check the values . however my input value of the last checkbox has an extra space as shown below

```
 print '<form action="process.pl " method="POST" id="sel">';
 print '<input type="checkbox" onClick="checkedAll()">Select All<br />';
 foreach my $i (@robos) {
    print '<input type="checkbox" name="sel" value="';
    print $i;
    print '">';
    print $i;
    print '<br />';
}
 print '<input type="submit" value="submit">';
 print '</form>';

 print "response " . Dumper \$data;
```

however in Process.pl the selected value is retrieved using

```
   @server = $q->param('sel');
```

but the response of selection is

```
 print "response " . Dumper \@server; => is showing [ 'ar', 'br', 'cr ' ]; which is
```

showing an additional space after cr . I dont know whats is wrong .

In my flat file i have

```
RMCList:ar:br:cr
```

i am then reading the details into an array and splitting using

```
  foreach my $ln (@lines) 
  { 
  if ($ln =~ /^RMCList/) 
 { 
@robos = split (/:/,$ln);
 }
 } #### end of for statement 
shift (@robos); 
print "The robos are ", (join ',', map { '"' . $_ . '"' } @robos), "\n";
```

This is showing the robos are:

```
"ar","br","cr
"
```

Comment: Presumably, that space is already present inside `@robos` – have you tried looking at that data? Note that you should escape your dumps: `use HTML::Entities;`, then `print encode_entities Dumper \@robos`.

Comment: yes i have looked on the content of @robos by print "the robos are @robos\n"; how will i come to know whether there is an extra space after last element

Comment: By putting quotes around each element: `print "The robos are ", (join ',', map { '"' . $_ . '"' } @robos), "\n"`

Comment: its showing a space for print encode_entities Dumper \@robos      $VAR1 = [ 'ar', 'br', 'cr ' ];

Comment: i dont understand its still showing a space . i am parsing the list from a flat file . i checked the flat file there is no space after cr.

Comment: In my flat file i have RMCList:ar:br:cr  i am then reading the details into an array and splitting using foreach my $ln (@lines)        ############################# parsing all the flatfile details ############
  {
 if ($ln =~ /^RMCList/)
  {
   @robos  = split (/:/,$ln);

  }
       
     } #### end of for statement

shift (@robos);  i then used ur  print join . but its showing a space after last value

Comment: How are you reading the values into `@lines`? Do the elements inside that array end with newlines? If so, does `chomp @lines` before your loop over `@lines` solve the problem?

Comment: open INFILE, "<path" or die "Cannot read file $infilename; $!\n";   #opening flatfile
 @lines = <INFILE>; # load file into a list of lines
 close(INFILE);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While reading the file into `@lines`, you forgot to remove the newline. This newline is interpreted as a simple space in a HTML document.

Remove the newlines with the [`chomp` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) like

```
chomp @lines;
```

before looping over the lines.

---

Actually, don't read the file into an array at all, unless you have to access each line more than once. Otherwise, read one line at the time:

```
open my $infile, "<", $filename or die "Cannot open $filename: $!";
my @robos;
while (my $ln = <$infile>) {
    chomp $ln;

    @robos = split /:/, $ln if $ln =~ /^RMCList/;
}
```